# Stream a webcam video using flask and h264 codec

Tags: python-3.x, flask, http-live-streaming, openh264

I need to stream from the PC camera using Python, I would prefer to use h264 as a codec to have a light video than to send single frames as images that weigh a lot. I searched a lot on the internet and did a lot of tests but I can't get it to work, can anyone help me? As I said I would like to avoid sending single frames as images because they weigh too much and I cannot guarantee real-time streaming since the device will be connected in 4G. I was able to install and use the codec and I can also generate the video but I don't really know how to stream it with Flask.